# How can I set up PyCharm to launch from the Launcher?

Tags: launcher, icons

I have installed PyCharm on my brand new Ubuntu 13.10 laptop.

To launch PyCharm, I find I must navigate to the directory that pycharm lives in, and execute it from there as such:

```
cd home/matt/software/pycharm/bin sh pycharm.sh
```

I hope this isn't asking too much, but I would like to be able to click on an icon in the Launcher to launch this application.

I tried right-clicking on the PyCharm icon in the Launcher when the app is running and selecting "Lock To Launcher" but this doesn't work (after pinning, when I try to run the software this way, the icon throbs in a very awkward manner a few times and does nothing).

A small app called Alacart was rumoured to be useful, but I have no idea how it works, and it appears useless.  I'm not sure why the authors teased us with a "Help" button if there are no help files written for us to view.

Further attempt has included reading page after page of technical documentation on how to write scripts that will somehow help me customize my experience.

**How can I set up PyCharm to launch from the Launcher???**

Comment: "Lock to launcher" button works on UBUNTU LTS 16.04, PyCharm 2018.2

Comment: On Ubuntu 18.0x: i. launch pycharm, ii. right click pycharm icon on the launcher, , iii. in the dropdown list, select "Add to Favourites".

Answer (score 400, accepted):

PyCharm can create it's own launcher icon (but it's not created by default).

All you have to do is:

1. Start PyCharm.
2. From the Tools menu, select "Create Desktop Entry..."
3. Tick the corresponding box if you want the launcher for all users.
4. If you selected "Create entry for all users", you will be asked for your password.
5. A green message bubble should appear informing you that it was successful.
6. You should then be able to find PyCharm in the Unity Dash or pin it to the launcher.

Note: You may need a system restart before it appears.

Comment: Thanks for you answer!  I did what you recommended, but alas,  when I click on the icon I now have pinned to the Launcher, it just throbs in a very awkward manner a few times and does nothing.  Very confusing..

Comment: @MattO'Brien Can you find a PyCharm file in `~/.local/share/applications` (for your user) or `/usr/share/applications` (for all users). Right click this > Properties, and check the 'Command' field.

Comment: The 'Command' field says, 
"/home/matt/software/pycharm/bin/pycharm.sh" %f
Is there something wrong with this?

Comment: @MattO'Brien I think you just need to run this `chmod a+x /home/matt/software/pycharm/bin/pycharm.sh`.

Comment: Updated to the latest community edition, it does not update the menu entry.

Comment: Is there any way to do this from the command-line to automate the process? Would that be a new question?

Comment: Thanks, it works with the latest edition as well! +1

Comment: I am using PyCharm CE, and there is no "Create Desktop Entry..." in the Tools menu.

Comment: @mhaghighat Open PyCharm go to `Help| Find action| Type "Create Desktop entry"`

Comment: @Ash: manually grepping for "Create Desktop entry" no longer yields joy. Recent versions of PyCharm appear to have *completely* removed this useful functionality. [mightypile](https://askubuntu.com/users/118036/mightypile)'s [general-purpose solution](https://askubuntu.com/a/909246/415719) is everyone's best bet, now.

Comment: This approach does not work sometimes when you download a new version.

Comment: Works without any problem in Ubuntu 22.04 / PyCharm 2022.1.3

Comment: It's present in PyCharm CE 2023.2.3

Comment: What's surprising to me is that PyCharm does not ask you to do this after installing.

Answer (score 21):

The "purest" method, in my opinion, is to simply create a launcher in a text editor that looks about like this:

```
[Desktop Entry]
Version=1.0
Type=Application
Name=PyCharm
Icon=/opt/pycharm-2017.1.1/bin/pycharm.png
Exec="/opt/pycharm-2017.1.1/bin/pycharm.sh" %f
Comment=The Drive to Develop
Categories=Development;IDE;
Terminal=false
StartupWMClass=jetbrains-pycharm
```

I believe this one was created by JetBrains, but you can type your own. Then save it to /home/yourname/.local/share/applications/appname.desktop for a launcher tied to your own login, or to /usr/share/applications/appname.desktop if you want it to apply to other users of your system.

Obviously, once editing, you can modify the icon, etc. And you can transfer this skill to other apps or tasks.

Comment: As of today (May 24, 2021) in Ubuntu 16.04.7 LTS (now on ESM) the path: `/opt/pycharm-2017.1.1/bin/` no longer exists and is replaced by `/snap/pycharm-community/current/bin/`. Note that `current` is symbolic link to `238` which is probably the build number which changes on **pycharm** updates. Don't forget to `chmod a+x appname.desktop`.

Comment: This workes only one time for me. After closing PyCharm I cannot start it again before I reboot.

Answer (score 4):

I had the same problem after "Create Desktop Entry...".
This is what solved my problem:
Go to the bin folder of the PyCharm and add following line to the beginning of `pycharm.sh` script:

```
export JDK_HOME='your java home folder'
```

and save the file. Now, run the launcher entry from Unity.

Answer (score 2):

There is a program called "main menu" available from the software centre. It allows you to make launchers for any command.

Also you need to run the `cd` and the launch as one command like this:

```
sh -c "cd /folder/to/go/to  && launch-command -options"
```

Click new item
[image: Click new item]

Enter a name for the launcher and the command, and maybe a picture
[image: Enter a name for the launcher and the command, and maybe a picture]

Comment: If you read the original version if this it may not work because of the lack of the single command using `sh`. Check edited version above.

Comment: please forgive me.  Once I create this New Item, what is the next step?  My Launcher is just sitting there in the "Main Menu" app.  How do I make this useful?

Comment: Ahh, here we get confused because I use Gnome not Unity. It should now appear in the Unity Dash. I assumed you could drag it from there to the unity launcher bar thingy like I can in Gnome.

Comment: Look in the folder: `~/.local/share/applications` can you see the launcher?
Open dconf editor (install if you don't have it) and go to:
"desktop-> unity-> launcher -> favorites"
Try adding the name of the launcher into that list.

Comment: Under  "desktop-> unity" we only have "lenses" and "runner."

Comment: I tried to log-out of Gnome and into unity but my unity now freezes rather than logs in. I had to kill it from a terminal session. I have a vague recollection of half removing unity because I hate it. This doesn't help you though. The dash icon works though, we are just left with trying to move that to the launcher?

Comment: ugh.  Why is it so hard to do such a simple task like this? I'm new to Unix-based systems and shocked at the difficulty of such mundane tasks.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/11994/discussion-between-julian-stirling-and-matt-obrien)

Comment: I think this program is called `alacarte` now.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming default Gnome WM, with the PyCharm Application open, right click on the dock icon. Choose "Add to Favorites" option.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

The PyCharm installation may come with a desktop file. This file can be copied to a working location. For example:

```
cp -v /snap/pycharm-community/current/meta/gui/pycharm-community.desktop ~/.local/share/applications
```

After copying this file, a working entry for PyCharm will be listed when you search for pycharm in "Show Launcher".