# Creating a Unity Launcher icon for PyCharm

Tags: unity, launcher, icons, .desktop

I can start, `PyCharm` from a shell script in a subdirectory of `/opt`. I get a gray question-mark icon (see attachment) rather than the orange/green `PyCharm` icon (see attachment). Note that the correct icon is in the `PyCharm` directory out-of-the-box.

I can lock this gray icon to  Launcher, but this icon does not work to launch `PyCharm`.

How can I get a Launcher button  to launch `PyCharm`?

(Ubuntu 14.10)

[image: Icon on launcher]
[image: PyCharm icon]

Answer (score 5, accepted):

#### Pycharm offers you to create a .desktop file on first run

When you start PyCharm for the first time, you will be offered the opportunity to set up *desktop integration*:

[image]

As you can see, you can tick: `Create desktop entry (integrate in sytem menu)`
This will (or would :)) create a `.desktop` file, `jetbrains-pycharm-ce.desktop`, in either `/usr/share/applictions` or `~/.local/share/applications`, depending on if you chose `For all users` or not.

#### What if you missed the message?

If you missed the message, you can simply temporarily rename the folder:

```
~/.PyCharm40
```

...and restart `PyCharm`, since the absence of this folder will make `PyCharm` assume you run it for the first time. Then, after things are done, you can simply remove the newly created `~/.PyCharm40` folder and rename the original folder.

From then on, you can simply run `Pycharm` from its own launcher.

[image]

#### Note

Although the message in the window says: `You can use File | Settings to configure any of these settings later`, I found *a lot* of settings options, but not the one to create a "Desktop Entry". It looks like the method above is the only option :)

Comment: @JoshuaFox perfect! glad it works.

Comment: This not seems to work with version 5... This accepted answer here is better : http://askubuntu.com/questions/391439/how-can-i-set-up-pycharm-to-launch-from-the-launcher

Answer (score 0):

You can make a .desktop file in /usr/share/applications.

1. Run `sudo gedit /usr/share/applications/python.desktop`
2. Enter this code and edit it to match your program:
   `[Desktop Entry]
   Version=1.0
   Name=[choose a name]
   Type=Application
   Comment=[description]
   Exec=[/path/to/executable]
   Icon=[path/to/icon]
   Terminal=false`
3. Navigate to `/usr/share/applications` and drag the new file to your launcher.

Comment: What is the use of posting a random .desktop file? Posts on how to create a "general" launcher already exist plenty on AU

Comment: @JacobVlijm But do people ever search?

Comment: No, that's why the "duplicates" exist, but first we need to find out a few things to see if it is.

Comment: It turns out the `.desktop` file, created by `PycCharm` is quite different,  includes the (important) line `StartupWMClass=jetbrains-pycharm-ce` and desktop integration includes more than just the `.desktop` file.

Comment: Of course it needs more than that. The executable is very important.