# Unity 17.04 Desktop Launcher problem for PyCharm

Tags: unity, launcher, 17.04, pycharm

I have just installed the final 17.04 Release.  Having problems with the Unity Launcher (not Dash, don't use that), *compared to what has always worked* in 16.04 & 14.04.

[To create a shortcut on Launcher I always run the program first from the shell, then when it's running I right-click its icon in Launcher and **Lock to Launcher**: if that is not the right way to do things let me know.]

Installed PyCharm (2017.1.1) via tar image from JetBrains.  When running I **Lock to Launcher** its icon as usual.  But when I exit PyCharm the icon is removed from Launcher (no other app behaves like this)?

EDIT in response to @Videonauth's comment:

From Unity Dash "pycharm" does **not** find any matching application.

It is "installed" by untaring into `/usr/share` and I did a `ln -s ../share/pycharm/pycharm-community-2017.1.1/bin/pycharm.sh /usr/bin/pycharm`, as I did in 16.04.

However, I see in my 16.04 that Dash **does** find "pycharm", and shows its icon (then again, it's already locked to Launcher, if that makes a difference).  OTOH, under 16.04 I initially did some kind of "Ubuntu install" of PyCharm.  I had problems (can't recall what, may well have been to do with unable to then get updates), and was advised to remove that and do by manual untar method; but it might have left something around to be found from dash, I don't know.

So: What is the relevance of whether it is found in Dash/what do I have to do?  And the fact that you ask that and talk about locking it from there, are you saying that my method of running an app from terminal and locking it while running is not a good idea?

OK, I have just found [How can I set up PyCharm to launch from the Launcher?](https://askubuntu.com/q/391439/475088).  I must look at that....

Comment: If you open the dash and type in 'pycharm' do you get a result? Have you tried to drag it from there to the launcher bar?

Comment: @Videonauth: updated my question.

Comment: No running from terminal and locking an application is mostly what I do too. Should be a perfect fine solution. The way i install PyCharm is only the un-tar method but I'm using normally a folder within my home directory which i call `.pycharm` and then run the `~/.pycharm/bin/pycharm.sh`. I just asked because while you first setup PyCharm you getting asked to implement commandline and desktop symbols and if you skip this PyCharm behaves how you have described it, even under 16.04. You can initiate this step from the Tools menu inside PyCharm if you need to.

Comment: Make sure you check `/.local/share/applications` (i think this is it) if it contains a file called `jetbrains-pycharm-ce.desktop`. if not the launcher may loose your locked icon due to it has no reference to remember it. (Thats my theory why this happens, but I'm not claiming to be correct on that this is why I not wrote an answer and just replying here in comments, I'm still on 16.10 and have not switched yet to 17.04)

Comment: @Videonauth Yes I did have that file when still not working.  I followed https://askubuntu.com/q/391439/475088 anyway, and let PyCharm do its own **Create Desktop Entry**, did it a couple of times, rebooted, cussed a bit, and now it's all working!  Thanks for your input.