# Launch IntelliJ without terminal command everytime

Tags: intellij

I have installed the latest version of IntelliJ 2019.3 community edition on my laptop which is running Ubuntu V19.04. Recently IntelliJ developed a problem where a normal way to start it was not working at all, so i am launching it by going into its `/bin` folder and write `./idea/sh` to start the application.

My question here is how can I make IntelliJ start without going to its directory and type a command to run it everytime?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How can I set up PyCharm to launch from the Launcher?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/391439/how-can-i-set-up-pycharm-to-launch-from-the-launcher) (also applies to IntelliJ IDEA)

Comment: Thanks for pointing the above answers, they solved my problem. How silly of me, anyways thanks. :)